# Plotting a 3D heat map

Tags: python, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, heatmap

I have a 3D array sized (100,519,492). I want to plot a 3D heat map, where color is defined by the array values and the locations are defined by the index in the array. I have tried googling around and I haven't come anywhere near close to getting a result.

I essentially want to plot this 2D data set 100 times, forming areas that are colored in based on the array value (in this case the value was set to be either 0-white or red-1):

[image]

I have tried following this guide: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/3d-heatmap-in-python/, but I get

```py
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape.  Mismatch is between arg 0 with shape (492,) and arg 1 with shape (519,).
```

```py
# importing required libraries
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

x = np.arange(0,492) #Number of columns in my 3d data array
y = np.arange(0,519) # Number of rows
z = np.arange(0,100) # Number of 2D slices making the 3D array
colo = ODS_diff # ODS_diff is the 3D array
  
# creating figures
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
  
# setting color bar
color_map = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.Greens_r)
color_map.set_array(colo)
  
# creating the heatmap
ax.scatter(x, y, z, marker='s',
                 s=200, color='red')
plt.colorbar(colo)
  
# adding title and labels
ax.set_title("3D Heatmap")
ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z-axis')
  
# displaying plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (we don't have `colo`).

Comment: Also, as per the [matplotlib user guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/quick_start.html) and [API reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/index.html#module-pylab) (search for "pylab"), you should not be using pylab anymore.

Comment: colo is just the variable name assigned to by data

Comment: (1) But we do not have any data to test your code. (2) You never even use `colo` to color your data.

Comment: On which line are you getting the error, the scatter plot line?

Comment: colo is used to on ln18 to set the color bar scale, the error occurs on ln21 'ax.scatter...'

Comment: (1) You need to make a `meshgrid` of your points since your points are not all the same shape (nor are they 3d). It's not clear to me how you plan on visualizing this since you would just end up with a cube of colors and you'd only be able to see the outside surface (because the outer points would block the inner points). (2) You set all the colors to red.

Comment: Do you mean something like,                                                                                      
 x= np.linspace(0,519) # num row
y =np.linspace(0,492) # num cols
z= np.linspace(0,100) # num slices

X,Y,Z = np.meshgrid(x,y,z)

Comment: As you can see on the 2D plot, most of the plot will be empty.

Comment: Yes, something along those lines. But because you're saying some of it is empty, you won't want to plot all the points. You can probably make use of a masked array to hide the points that you don't need. Though, I'll be honest, I have no clue what I am looking at with the 2D plot. You may want to add some axes and explain what the plot is showing.

Comment: I may have found a better approach: https://plotly.com/python/3d-volume-plots/

Comment: Either my PC is too slow, or it isn't working. I think I better make a new question, as the code is entirely different. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually I think I will have the same problem with the other method, I will need a masked array

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You are (or rather your reference is) overcomplicating

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# different from yours, see below
x = y = z = np.linspace(-2, 2, 41)
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)
values = 2*X*X - Y*Y + 1/(Z*Z+1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
scatter = ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c=values, cmap='PRGn')
fig.colorbar(scatter, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

That said ("It's easy if you ask the right guys") I have to make a remark about

```
x = np.arange(0,492) #Number of columns in my 3d data array
y = np.arange(0,519) # Number of rows
z = np.arange(0,100) # Number of 2D slices making the 3D array
```

With a grid with shape `(41, 41, 41)` the density of the points/spheres is already too much, and it takes a couple of seconds to render in the first place, and even more when I try to rotate or zoom.  Imagine what happens when in place of ~64000 points you want to represent ~25 million points.
It is possible that you want to sample a subset of your grid.